# In jQuery uploadify show the images as thumbnails BEFORE the upload by the user's filepath

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to make an uploadify upload to my server, and make thumbnails from the user's images on the fly.

I just need the filepath for each upload. However the only parameter i found in the Javascript is the substringed filename.

Instead of `ohmygoditsantaclaus.jpg` I want the full path like `C:/Etc/Etcetera/Daddy/ohmygoditsantaclaus.jpg`. If i have this, i can make a div container easily put the image to it, and resize it with CSS.

Thanks for the help. PS: I used Uploadify v1.6.2

Here is the [jQuery Uploadify v.1.6.2](http://phpviddleruploadify.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/phpviddler/js/uploadify/jquery.uploadify%20%28Source%29.js) and the [Uploader.FLA](http://phpviddleruploadify.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/phpviddler/js/uploadify/uploader.fla) i currently using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the full path with either JavaScript or Flash, like:

> C:/Etc/Etcetera/Daddy/ohmygoditsantaclaus.jpg

It's a security thing.

Also, even if you could, you sure as heck can't do the next thing you want to do:

> If i have this, i can make a div
>   container easily put the image to it,
>   and resize it with CSS.

You can't access random images on the user's hard disk using a `file://` URI and place them on your webpage.

---

You can instead use something like http://www.plupload.com/ - once the user has selected their images to upload, you can resize images client side.

If you want to show thumbnails before uploading, I know Flash can do it. I'm not sure if anything else can.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a major security problem, and for all I know, this won't and should not work.